# Create class instance from variable in Zend Framework

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

i have `class Plugin_Magazine extends Zend_Controller_Action`

in some views i need to call `static function test()` from it.

in view i do folowing:

```
$class_name = 'Plugin_'.$plugin;
$class_name::test();
```

as a result i have

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Zend_Controller_Action::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract, none given

but, if i create `class Plugin_Magazine` w\o **extends** all works fine.

question is: can i somehow do what i need or just forget about inheritance?

Comment: First question is: why is a call to a static method resulting in a call to the constructor?

Comment: problem solved with call_user_func(array($controller_name, 'test'))

Comment: Mark your answers as solved then and write an answer, don't post it there as it's still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a Request object to the constructor of the Action class

At somepint your doing this:

```
 $pm = new Plugin_Magazine();
```

But you need to pass the request object:

```
 $pm = new Plugin_Magazine($this->getRequest());
```

As for this call:

```
$class_name = 'Plugin_'.$plugin;
$class_name::test();
```

Why do you need a static function in an Action? This doesn't seem right, if it's reusable logic that exists in an Action that it should be moved elsewhere to where it can be used more easily, like into a Model.

Comment: actually static or public will be test() doesn't matters.
tried to do $plugin = new Plugin_Magazines($this->getRequest());
Plugin by name 'GetRequest' was not found in the registry